# Mixture random variable density

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, mixture-distribution

I have $X = B_1X_1 + B_2X_2 + ... + B_nX_n$ where the $X_i$ are independent random variables and the $B_i$ are independent $Bern(p_i)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i =1$. I want to find the PDF and CDF of X and compute its hazard function in terms of the hazard functions of its components. It was suggested that I use conditioning to calculate the PDF and CDF, but I'm not sure how to condition in this case, or what even to condition on. Any hints on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not a mixture but a randomized sum.

Comment: Would it make sense to talk about the density of each product in the sum?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? What you’re describing is a distribution of a sum of random variables, not mixture.